# Perform a command in another shell from Vim

Tags: linux, vim

I use two monitors in my development workflow, one is a fullscreen vim session for editing and the other is a fullscreen terminal where I run `make && ./test` to show results. Fairly often I find myself opening a bunch of other windows in the background (browers, more shells etc). I don't like this for a few reasons:

- I don't like having to remember how many times I have to hit tab before I get my make window.
- There's no strong visual feedback in Ubuntu for which window is currently in focus. I could probably do something about that but that's a separate problem.
- To be honest I'm lazy, and `:w alt-tab up-arrow enter alt-tab` is far too many keystrokes.

I think a good solution might be to have a vim command that runs `make && ./test` in the other window, but I can't think of how to do this. I could write a server/client script that waits from some notification from vim then runs the command but it really seems like there should be a simpler solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/benmills/vimux (see http://www.drbunsen.org/text-triumvirate.html for some more context)

Comment: It does not exactly address your question, however I wrote a vim script to run a build in the background and retain control of vim.  Maybe it will give you some ideas: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1391

Comment: I don't want to sound elitist, but you are using vim wrong. Vim has a built in make commmand (try :make) and you can certainly follow it up with a :!./test once the make completes without error. The key to the :make vim command is that it supports parsing of errors from the make command into a quick-fix list, which is among the top 10 reasons why I use vim in the first place.

Comment: Wouldn't say _"using vim wrong"_, more like _"missing out on a super-cool feature"_

Comment: Yep I know about `:make` and `:!cmd`. They don't help me display the results on another screen, which is what I'm trying to do. This is just a personal preference, I don't really like quick-fix lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Jim's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224301/perform-a-command-in-another-shell-from-vim#comment18012017_13224301) for getting me started. This is what I'm doing now:

On the first monitor: `tmux new-session -s dev` (creates a new tmux session named dev)

On the second monitor: `tmux new -t dev` (connects to that new session)

On the second monitor: `Ctrl-b + c` (creates a new window)

I [forked vimux](https://github.com/alexlegg/vimux) and wrote functions to send commands to another window. So now in vim I can use `:call VimuxRunCommandWin("make && ./test")`.

And I think that's probably enough procrastination for one day...

Comment: Why don't you simply use two vertical panes in a single tmux session? `Ctrl-b + %`.

Comment: I don't like stretching a window over two screens. I only had to add about two functions to get what I needed anyway.

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem by making something new and sharing it.